# Creating Icons on Application Toolbar via SAS autoexec (Base SAS)

Tags: command-line, sas

I would like to know if it is possible (and if so how) to add buttons to the SAS Application Toolbar via SAS script.

For instance, I have a button which submits "signoff" via the command line, and would like to distribute this to the rest of the team via our shared autoexec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the catalog that contains your new toolbar items somewhere everyone can get to.  In your autoexec create a libname to the folder that contains the saved catalog.  Then use this command in the autoexec file (replacing the libname and toolbar name with your specific details):

```
dm "toolload bar <libname>.profile.<name_of_toolbar>";
```